# How to continue a table in one database in another database

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am basically curious about if it is possible to continue a table that has been created in one database to be continued in another. For example, if a table has been created for users ,each one having a unique id that increments, is in one database but becomes "full", can that same table be continued in another database with the unique ids still being incremented even if that database is on another server.

I apologize in advance if this is a noob question. I am new to MySql.

Comment: for starters, you can have a view that does a union on tables across database and probably assign an `instead of trigger` to handle inserts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables never get full unless you run out of physical disk space. They can get really loaded down with data, though, if you have a large volume of users.

What you're talking about in general terms is either partitioning, sharding or clustering. Usually this is done for performance reasons, not because any particular table is physically too large. Be wary about doing this, though, because the overhead of this change is significant and will require a very disciplined effort to use correctly throughout your application.

If you're using some kind of Object Relationship Mapper (ORM) to interface with your database, this may have a feature that makes this easier from a programming perspective.

Unless you have tens of millions of rows there's probably ways to tune your database to get the performance you require.

Comment: what do you do then if you run out of physical disk space

Comment: You buy a bigger disk, generally, or you start deleting data you don't need. We live in an age where 1TB of storage costs less than $100, so usually it's not a concern unless you're on a very small VPS with an extremely limited storage allowance. I really doubt that your user table could exhaust one of those, though, as even the smallest still have 10-20GB of storage which is often more than enough to get started.